# Regarding uniform convergence on [a, infinity)

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $a > 0$, then the convergence of $(e^{-nx})$ is uniform on the interval $[a, \infty)$ but not uniform on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Let $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

I know that $(e^{-nx})$ converges pointwise to $0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ (this was the first part of this question).

By following the example in my textbook, I did the following:

Let $n_k = k$ and let $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$, then:

$f_{nk}(x_k) = \frac{1}{e}$

It follows that:

$|f_{nk}(x_k) - f(x_k)| = |\frac{1}{e} - 0| = \frac{1}{e} < \epsilon$

This shows that the convergence is NOT uniform on $[0, \infty)$ since there is no n corresponding to $\epsilon = \frac{1}{e}$... right?

What I don't know how to do is this - I'm not sure how to show it IS uniform for $[a,\infty)$.  I tried this:

$ 0 ≤ x ≤ a$

$\frac{1}{e^{nx}} ≤ \frac{1}{e^{na}} ≤ \frac{2}{e^{nx}} ≤ \epsilon$

But I'm not sure if this is what I'm supposed to do or not.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the function
$$f_n\colon x\mapsto e^{-nx}$$
is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ so
$$\sup_{x\in[a,+\infty)}|f_n(x)|=e^{-na}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
hence we have uniform convergence on the interval $[a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$.

**Remark 1:** You have a mistake in your answer: we have a pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$ only on the interval $[0,\infty)$ to the function $f$ defined by
$$f(0)=1\quad;\quad f(x)=0,\;\forall x>0$$
**Remark 2:**
Since $f$ isn't continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and the functions $f_n$ are continuous then the convergence isn't uniform on $[0,\infty)$.